# Usage of Double and Decimal in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've searched this up a little bit but I haven't found the correct information for my request. In my MySQL table I am storing a double, some examples of the double would be 5.60 or 2.44. I'm wondering if I could store a double with a max length just like INT(9). Would I use Decimal(2,2) or would I use Double(2)?

Comment: One thing to note: `decimal(2,2)` would mean that the whole number would have maximum precision equal to 2 (only 2 digits overall), so you would probably need `decimal(3,2)` to store value like `2.44` (3 digits).

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy so what do the (3, 2) values mean? 3 meaning 3 digits and 2 meaning two decimal places?

Comment: It's explained well in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For FLOAT and DOUBLE, in MySQL the precision value is used only to determine storage size. A precision from 0 to 23 results in a 4-byte single-precision FLOAT column. A precision from 24 to 53 results in an 8-byte double-precision DOUBLE column.

The DECIMAL and NUMERIC types store exact numeric data values. These types are used when it is important to preserve exact precision, **for example with monetary data.**

Comment: It's also said that it permits some non standard format where you can specify the number of digit after the  decimal point : DOUBLE PRECISION (M, D) where the value​ stored maybe up  to M  digits of which D digits may be after the decimal point. See here : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html